# Is it possible to compile an iPhone App for IOS 4.0 using Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, xcode4, compilation

Does anyone know how to compile an iPhone app targeting iOS 4.0 using Xcode 4?

It seems that it is only possible to select iOS 4.2 as target.

Thanks in advance

Peter

Comment: are you sure? you have IOS sdk 4.0 too?

Comment: Where you are locating target iOS?

Answer (score 5):

There's a "Deployment Target" setting and a "Base SDK" setting.  You can set the deployment target by clicking on the project name at the top of the tree, then bring up the "Summary" page.  Deployment Target is the 4th item, and can be set to 4.0.

"Base SDK" is on the "Build Settings" page and is usually the latest SDK you have installed, but can be set to older SDKs if you go to the trouble to keep them around.  Normally you shouldn't need to though, because apps built with newer SDKs should run on older iOS versions as long as you restrict your coding to the older API.

So an app built with the 4.2 SDK should run fine on iOS 4.0 if you set the deployment target to 4.0 or earlier and don't use any methods introduced after 4.0.

See also:

- [How to target previous version of iOS in XCode4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692111/how-to-target-previous-version-of-ios-in-xcode4)
- [What's the real difference between Base SDK and Deployment Target or Deployment OS Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750468/whats-the-real-difference-between-base-sdk-and-deployment-target-or-deployment-o)
- [How to target 4.2 version with XCode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253695/how-to-target-4-2-version-with-xcode-4)
- [iOS deployment target set to iOS 4.2. Will the app run on devices running earlier versions of iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747299/ios-deployment-target-set-to-ios-4-2-will-the-app-run-on-devices-running-earlier)